# How to iterate through XML tags using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

Currently I have the following `XML` something like this:

```
<item>
   <title> this is title 1 </title>
   <description> description 1 </description>
   <pubDate> date 1 </pubDate>
</item>

<item>
   <title> this is title 2 </title>
   <description> description 2 </description>
   <pubDate> date 2 </pubDate>
</item>
```

I'm using `jsoup` but the result that I got is:

```
this is title 1
this is title 2
description 1
description 2
date 1
date 2
```

The actual result that I want:

```
this is title 1
description 1
date 1
this is title 2
description 2
date 2
```

I'm still a beginner in android. I want to achieve this using `Jsoup`. A simple sample code would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. Yes it did. I just customized the code to my own needs. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet that prints all children of the `item` elements:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = 
                "<item>\r\n" + 
                "   <title> this is title 1 </title>\r\n" + 
                "   <description> description 1 </description>\r\n" + 
                "   <pubDate> date 1 </pubDate>\r\n" + 
                "</item>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "<item>\r\n" + 
                "   <title> this is title 2 </title>\r\n" + 
                "   <description> description 2 </description>\r\n" + 
                "   <pubDate> date 2 </pubDate>\r\n" + 
                "</item>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        for (Element item : doc.select("item")) {
            Elements children = item.children();
            for (Element child : children) {
                System.out.println(child.text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> this is title 1
>   description 1
>   date 1
>   this is title 2
>   description 2
>   date 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">" +
                "<item>\n" +
                "   <title> this is title 1 </title>\n" +
                "   <description> description 1 </description>\n" +
                "   <pubDate> date 1 </pubDate>\n" +
                "</item>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<item>\n" +
                "   <title> this is title 2 </title>\n" +
                "   <description> description 2 </description>\n" +
                "   <pubDate> date 2 </pubDate>\n" +
                "</item></xml>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        for (Element e : doc.select("item")) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }

}
```